# Как во Views можно обратиться к static?

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я работая во Views обратиться к файлу, расположенному в папке static?
Сам static настроен,  html страница берет из него css/js, но хочу обратиться к файлу через views при написании алгоритма

Comment: Можете, как к любому другому файлу.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример?

Comment: @Алексей https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912243/11214129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример. Ответ общий, совместно с nomnoms12 и Дмитрий Дмитрук

```
from django.conf import STATIC_ROOT
import os

with open(os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, <path_to_static_file>)) as file:
  # do anything with file
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912243/11214129